# XML document outline window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

A google search didnt give a result, so I tought about asking here.

Is there a window in Visual Studio for XML that behaves like the document outline window on wpf/aspx/...

Would be nice to see the hierachy (xpath) on a large XML document, without trying to scroll to the parent node of a 5000 nodes item.

**Edit:**

I am using VS 2012, but if there is a window like this in VS 2013 I wouldnt mind using this for XML documents.

Comment: maybe could be useful that you mention wich version of visual studio.

Comment: What behavior do you mean?

Comment: Is it something like you get when you use the MSVC++ Debugger and choose View XML on a variable?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a native XML document outline available in any version of Visual Studio to date. The closest feature is [XML Schema Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716766(v=vs.110).aspx) that is available when you are creating or editing XSD documents that creates a graphical structure of your XML schema definition while you are building it.

I am not aware of any integrated extensions that have been completed to provide the document outline, but there are third party xml editors, such as [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-document-outline.aspx) or [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) that provide this, which are well worth the investment if you do a lot with XML. Perhaps even [XML Notepad](https://xmlnotepad.codeplex.com/) could provide the document outline you are looking for with no cost, but not sure if it handles large files as well as the commercial products.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning here that this answer is outdated (old question anyway) and there are now extensions that provide this functionality like 'xml language support' and others.